# How to save in local an image upload in a web application using plotly dash in python?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python, web-frameworks

I want to make an app using dash in which the user uploads an image, the application saves it in a predefined local folder, modifies this image and finally shows the original image and the modified one.

I have no problem loading the image, but I don’t know how to store it so I can modify it later.

Could someone guide me on how to do it? Any comments/experience would be greatly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand problem. How about `open()`, `write()`. `close()`? But if code runs on server then it can save it only on server - not on your local computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.